# Using numpy.random.normal

Tags: python, random, numpy

I have this code, which is part of a bigger code.

```
newimg = pf.getdata(name)
print newimg
newhdr = pf.getheader(name) 
normalNoise = np.random.normal(0,poisson)
test = newimg + normalNoise
```

pf is "pyfits" and "name" is the name of a .fits file that I read in. I want to take that .fits file and add noise to it in such a way that the amount of noise is randomly distributed among all the pixels. I would like to be able to add a greater amount of noise for a greater amount of standard deviations; in other words, the image should become less and less discernible as I increase the value of the variable "poisson." How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You seem to be pretty close, just need to generate more than a single random sample, I think `normalNoise = np.random.normal(0, poisson, size=newimg.shape)` will do it.